# Why does Bootstrap 4 use A3 page size as default?

Tags: bootstrap-4

The $print-page-size variable is defined as a3 by default.  Surely this is much larger than most people can print?  Here in the UK, printing on A4 (half that size) is normal?

Comment: this really causing me 1 working day to trace this because its under the @```media print``` this drive me nut

Answer (score 2):

From the [twbs/bootstrap issues page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25629)

Martijn Cuppens gave the following answer:

"We've removed the print hacks in v5. As for v4, I would indeed suggest using `@page { size: auto }`. Not planning on fixing this, since it might reintroduce other issues we had before."

So, it sounds like this is a bug and the only way to fix it for v4 is to override that css value. Or, you could upgrade to Bootstrap V5.

Comment: doesn't really explain why the hack was in there in the first place, but thanks!